# Some logic error or synatx error for the program

Tags: c, pointers

I'm learning pointers in C and I tried to write a program like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* getValue(int length)
{
   int *value,*index,data;
   value = malloc(length*sizeof(int));
   index = value;

   while(length>0){
     scanf("%d", &data);
     *index = data;
     index++;
     length--;
   }
   return (value);
}


int total(int length, int *data)
{
   int *index,sum,i;

   index = data;
   sum =0;
   for(i=0;i<length;i++){
       sum+= *index;
       index++;
   }
   return (sum);
}

int main()
{
   int i,j,ptrLength,num,sum,*lengthPtr,*lengthIndex,**ptr,**ptrIndex;

   lengthPtr = malloc(3*sizeof(int));
   lengthIndex = lengthPtr;
   ptr = malloc(3*sizeof(int *));
   ptrIndex = ptr;

   for(i=0;i<3;i++){
     printf("Enter the length and the value:");
     scanf("%d",ptrLength);
     *lengthIndex = ptrLength;
     lengthIndex++;     

     *ptrIndex = getValue(ptrLength);    
     ptrIndex++;
   }

   printf("Enter which one you want to calculate:");
   scanf("%d",&num);

   sum = total(lengthPtr[num-1], ptr[num-1]);
   printf("The sum is %d",sum);

   free(lengthPtr);
   free(ptr);
   return (0);
}
```

To try to allocate two arrays to hold the array's size and the value. The code can be compiled but didn't show what I thought.(It should print out one of the array's sum). But I don't know which part I got wrong... Could someone help me?

Comment: Also, in `scanf("%d",ptrLength);` you need to pass the address of the variable to receive the value: `scanf("%d",&ptrLength);`

Comment: You're freeing `ptr` but not the memory allocated in `getValue()` that each index points to.

Comment: If you compile with warnings (`gcc -Wall <filename>`) then you will see the `scanf` problem that @JohnnyMopp has alerted you to.

Comment: `35:10: warning: unused variable ‘j’ [-Wunused-variable]` -- get rid of it... Always compile with ***warnings enabled***. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow` for gcc/clang or for VS `/W3`. Other compilers will have the ability to provide warnings, you will have to consult the documentation for the proper switches. (your pointer use is fine)

Comment: Also, you cannot use any input function correctly unless you ***check the return***, e.g. `if (scanf("%d", &ptrLength) != 1) { /* handle error */ }`.

Comment: You should take note of the above comments, but I think that once the missing `&` is inserted, your code is doing basically what you want. With the error in place, you are probably seeing a segmentation fault inside `scanf()`, when you are passing an uninitialised integer value into what should be a pointer argument, and that is dereferenced.

Comment: I think what is best for you is to leave this peace of code alone.
start with a simpler example, and build it gradually to a bigger piece of code.

always remember that pointers are variables. they are variables that stores numbers. these numbers happen to be addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Only problem is with `scanf` you need to store it in some address.

```
scanf("%d",&ptrLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in your code.I iterate over the arrays (int*) using operator `subscribt []` (Returns a reference to the element at position n in the array) and i fix some errors.

you must check if malloc successeded or failed in allocation! You have memory leak cos you didn't free the `array(int**)` you just freed the pointer!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* getValue(int length)
{
   int *value,*index,data;
   value = malloc(length*sizeof(int));
   if(value==NULL){
      printf("malloc failed!");
       return NULL; 
   }
    for(int i=0 ;i<length; i++){
     scanf("%d", &data);
     value[i]=data;
   }
   return value;
}


int total(int length, int *data)
{
   int sum,i;
   sum =0;
   for(i=0;i<length;i++){
       sum+= data[i];
   }
   return (sum);
}

int main()
{
   int i,num,sum;

   int *Lengths =(int *)malloc(3*sizeof(int));
   if(Lengths==NULL){
       printf("malloc failed!");
       return 1;
   }
   int **Arrays = (int **)malloc(3*sizeof(int *));
   if(Arrays==NULL){
      printf("malloc failed!");
       return 1; 
   }

   for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
     printf("Enter the Array length: ");
     scanf("%d",&Lengths[i]);
     printf("Fill the array with values: ");
     Arrays[i] = getValue(Lengths[i]);    
   }

   printf("Enter which one you want to calculate:");
   scanf("%d",&num);

   sum = total(Lengths[num-1], Arrays[num-1]);
   printf("The sum is %d",sum);

   free(Lengths);
   for(int i=0; i<3;i++)
        free(Arrays[i]);
   free(Arrays);
}
```